# Probability finding a card in $n$ draws?

Tags: probability, card-games

I remember seeing this as a trick before. I tried to recreate it but it's proving to be difficult.

I have a deck of $13$ cards, consisting of ace through king. I have a card number in my head (ace, $2$-$10$, jack, queen, king). What is the probability of finding it in $n$ draws? After each draw I put the card back and shuffle the deck.

Comment: First, you don't need to have infinitely many cards. Consider simply a deck of $13$ cards (All the numbers) and once you have drawn a card, you put it back in the deck and reshuffle.

Comment: As it is a deck with infinitely many cards (*i.e. an infinite shoe*), we may treat this as though it were drawing with replacement.  The probability of seeing the first ace after exactly $n$ draws will correspond to finding a non-ace in the first $n-1$ draws followed by an ace for the $n$'th draw.  See the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) on wikipedia.

Comment: @Zubzub Fixed it

Comment: You've been back to visit the page since my comment (*as evidenced by your edit*) but you did not seem to acknowledge it.  Did you, or did you not understand my comment and still have a question?  It seemed pretty clear to me...

Comment: Sorry, I' m quite new at probability. I was checking the wiki in your link.

Comment: Perhaps the "trick" you are trying to recall is to consider the complementary event:  What is the probability of *not* finding the selected card in $n$ draws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is essentially drawing with replacement, we notice that any particular draw will be the card we are looking for with probability $\frac{1}{13}$ and will not be with probability $\frac{12}{13}$.

As each draw is *independent* of one another, the probability of a specific sequence of draws will be the product of the probabilities of each draw individually.  E.g. Ace-Ace-Nonace in that order will occur with probability $\frac{1}{13}\cdot\frac{1}{13}\cdot\frac{12}{13}$.

There are two possible interpretations of the question I can think of.

> What is the probability that the first ace is drawn on the $n$'th draw?

This follows the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with $p=\frac{1}{13}$.  This corresponds to getting $n-1$ non-ace cards in a row followed by an ace.  This occurs then with probability $\frac{12}{13}\cdot\frac{12}{13}\cdots\frac{12}{13}\cdot\frac{1}{13}=(\frac{12}{13})^{n-1}\cdot\frac{1}{13}$

> What is the probability that within the first $n$ draws, at least one ace is drawn? (*but it doesn't necessarily need to be the $n$'th draw where the ace occurs*)

Getting at least one ace within the first $n$ draws means that the first ace we see occurs within the first $n$ draws, so we may simply sum over the geometric distribution up to $n$.  $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(\frac{12}{13})^{k-1}\frac{1}{13}$ which may be simplified using what you know about geometric series.

An alternate method to calculate this is by recognizing that getting at least one ace within the first $n$ draws is the opposite event of getting no aces within the first $n$ draws.  Getting no aces corresponds to not getting an ace for the first draw followed by not getting an ace for the second draw followed by...etc...

Getting no aces in $n$ draws has probability then $\frac{12}{13}\cdot\frac{12}{13}\cdots\frac{12}{13}=(\frac{12}{13})^n$ so getting at least one ace in $n$ draws has probability $1-(\frac{12}{13})^n$.  Had you simplified your geometric sum above, it would have arrived at this answer as well.

---

A word of warning, I mentioned that $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$, that is the probability event $A$ *and* event $B$ simultaneously occur is the probability of the product of their respective probabilities.  This is true **only** for independent events, and is in general **not** true for arbitrary events.