# Simple [visual] probability - drawing cards (find 2 in 10)

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I have simple probability problem.

I've researched (
[Probability finding a card in $n$ draws?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234151/probability-finding-a-card-in-n-draws) by @JMoravitz
 and made my calculations. But I am not sure if the result is correct. Could you please assure me?

Context: a deck of 10 cards: 8-hearts and 2-diamonds. 10 people drawing 1 random card in turns. (The first draws from 10cards, the second - from 9cards, etc.) What is the probability of drawing a diamond?

Here is my calculations, visually outlined: [(see pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95xrG.jpg)

Comment: The linked question is drawing *with* replacement so you would always be drawing from the same number of cards

Comment: oh, understood, my bad I appologize, I meant - no replacement ofc. So: Drawing from Diminishing number of cards is the correct idea here.

Comment: If each of the $10$ persons draws one of the $10$ cards then each of them has a chance of $\frac2{10}$ to draw a diamond. The $10$ cards are divided among the $10$ persons and each of them gets a card. The eventual order in which the persons receive a card is irrelevant.

Comment: The problem felt simmilar to Monty Python, are you sure the order is irrelevant here?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. You could say that the $10$ cards are placed blindly on the spots $1,2,\dots,10$. Can you find any reason why e.g. the probability that spot $3$ is covered with a diamond differs from the probability that spot $6$ is covered with a diamond? Btw, what I am saying must not be looked at as a solution of the linked question. Actually it is just a remark (so no answer) and it might be that I only brought confusion.

Comment: no, thank you, seems logical I agree, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing without replacement, a symmetry argument like drhab's comment says that the probability the $n$th card is a diamond is $\frac{2}{10}$ ans the $n$th draw is equally likely to be any of the ten cards, and two of those are diamonds

If you want the longer calculation then you need to consider three cases:

- No diamonds may have been chosen in the first $n-1$ draws.  This has probability $\frac{8 \times 7 \times \cdots (9-n)}{10 \times 9 \times \cdots (11-n)} = \frac{(11-n) \times  (10-n)}{10 \times 9 }$.  If so, the conditional probability the next is a diamond is $\frac2{11-n}$
- One diamond may have been chosen in the first $n-1$ draws.  This has probability $(n-1) \frac{2 \times 8 \times 7 \times \cdots (10-n)}{10 \times 9 \times \cdots (11-n)} = \frac{2(n-1)(11-n)}{10 \times 9 }$.  If so, the conditional probability the next is a diamond is $\frac1{11-n}$
- Two diamonds may have been chosen in the first $n-1$ draws.  This has probability $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} \frac{2 \times 1 \times 8 \times 7 \times \cdots (11-n)}{10 \times 9 \times \cdots (11-n)} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{10 \times 9}$.  If so, the conditional probability the next is a diamond is $\frac0{11-n}$

So the overall probability the $n$th card drawn is a diamond is $\frac{(11-n) \times  (10-n)}{10 \times 9 }\frac2{11-n} + \frac{2(n-1)(11-n)}{10 \times 9 }\frac1{11-n}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{10 \times 9} \frac0{11-n} = \frac{20-2n+2n-2+0}{90} = \frac{18}{90} = \frac{2}{10}$ as expected

Comment: I am greatful for that thorough explanation, I did not expect that! I am not sure I can say that you guys (Henry and drhab) made my day, but you were very close to that! Thank you all again!